# Docker Container size is smaller compared to its image

Tags: docker

I have been tasked to obtain the size of a specific micro service. Its docker image size from the build command 190MB. and when I create a container out of this image, I get a surprising result as the container shows it has a size of 102MB. This kind of confuses me, how is this possible? Can someone explain to me?

Comment: How did you measure the size of the container?

Comment: @adebasi  docker ps

Comment: Do you mean `docker ps -s`? That command shows two sizes. Is the size of the image based on the information from `docker images`? Please update your question with those details.